# Hashset Multiple Threads maintain integrity?

Tags: java

HashSet<> IPs = new HashSet<>();

I will have multiple threads accessing and modifying this. Will adding the word volatile be enough to prevent corruption? A basic explanation of how to prevent conflicting thread access will help me better understand these keywords I am not quite clear on.

Comment: volatile is not enough use synchronization technique by guarding hashset and allowing only one thread at a time to access hashset

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` only makes the variable itself threadsafe. This means assigning a new value or reading the variable is threadsafe, not methodcalls on the object stored in the variable. `Collections.synchronizedSet(Set set)` might need your needs.

```
HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> threadSafe = Collections.synchronizedSet(names);
```

Comment: can you give me an example of using this synchronizedSet method I am getting an error that I can't place a HashSet inside of it, I am sure it is some silly syntax error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package. The concurrent collections are quite [performant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). particularly `ConcurrentSkipListSet` and `CopyOnWriteArraySet`.